# Can I link from a button to a different button (on the same page)?

Tags: javascript, html

so I am fairly new to web developing, but I am currently trying to create a "tutorial" (about history of money). I have lots of different pop-up modals that open (on the same page) one after the other after a button is clicked. However, this makes it very hard to check if everything is all good because I have to go through every single pop-up (the url does not change, as pop-ups are opened using JS: `getElementbyId("Modal1".style.display="block"` or `display="none"`). I was now wondering if it is possible to link from one button to another element (button) on the same page so that I can access different sections of the tutorial via the URL. So simply for navigating more easily between different pop-ups.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you,
Lisa

Comment: I miss understand, you want to trigger another button or scroll to another block when user click in the button ?

Comment: You can get the `URL` with `window.location.href`. Then `split('?')[1]` on `?`.

Comment: @Mooga I do that already, but what I want to know is whether I can quickly access any special modal via URL. So imagine I have 100 Modals and want to go to #99, right now I have to click through every single one of them until I reach #99. Is it possible to go there straight away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a function like

```
function show(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
}
```

and then open the desired popup directly from the javascript console with

```
show("Modal1")
```